# In Android Studio IDE MotionLayout animations are not rendering

Tags: android, android-studio, animation

After installing a new version of android studio I managed to seen my animations play properly on screen. now, again I am back to always seeing only the end state of the animation. pressing play or dragging the progress pointer on the transition does nothing. Has anyone experienced this in Android Studio and know a fix?

Clarification: the issue only concerns Android Studio and not the motion layout animation on the final device. I want to be able to see and customize my Motion Layout in the IDE